# Support of chrome extension on electron apps

Tags: electron

I want to clarify first, I haven't even started on the electron app. Before I do I had this query:
Electron apps being powered by chromium internally (according to my understanding), is it possible to chrome extensions be used or at least somehow provide a provision in the electron app to use the chrome extension.

**Use case**:

I am planning to make a text editor for me tweaked to serve my purpose (I am a big fan of creating tools for myself to improve my productivity). I am planning to make it with the help of electron, but I love Grammarly extension and would love if I could include it.

Comment: You may want to look into the [BrowserWindow API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowaddextensionpath)